# Archive and archive all are grayed out in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Xamarin iOS for visual studio 2017 under windows 7, 
archive and archive all are grayed out, while they are enabled for Android projects, I'm connecting to El Capitan and everything works as expected.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building an app package for iOS follows a different workflow than for Android where you use the Archive command as noted in the docs:

> The Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio does not currently support the Archiving workflow for publishing iOS applications to the App Store. As a result, you have upload an IPA created via the Build Ad hoc IPA command, which is described below.

Go [here to the official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/) to see how this is done for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you have to select Release, Iphone, and IOS Project. in order to get Archive Menu Enabled.

and make sure your version of visual studio is higher than VS2019 16.3

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select Simulator in the device list. You need to either select your connected iPhone, or the "Remote Device" option. Refer the screenshot below for details.

[image]